# Refactoring Form_for Create Method for Comments in a Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I am working on my first polymorphic association relationship and I am having trouble refactoring my form_for create comments.

I tried going through the Polymorphic Association RailsCasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?view=asciicast, but it seems dated.

I have two questions:

1. How do I rewrite my comment_form partial so that it would work for anything commentable? The way I have it right now, it would only work for traveldeals since `(:commentable_id => @traveldeal.id)`.
2. When I create the comment, the commentable_type is empty. What is commentable_type and do I need to pass it in the form?

Thanks!

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

traveldeal.rb

```
class Traveldeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :commentable_id, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

traveldeal_show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/comment_form'  %>
```

_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for current_user.comments.build(:commentable_id => @traveldeal.id) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

<div>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>

<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id %>

<div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part that is dated in the Railscast are the routes.

To answer your first question: create your form like it is done in the Railscast:

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

If you do it like this `commentable_type` will be set automatically. You need the type so you know to what model a comment belongs. Note that you have to set `@commentable` in the method where you use the comment form.

E.g.

```
class TraveldealsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @traveldeal = @commentable = Traveldeal.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this one, Mischa. I failed to set @commentable for the show page as your answer indicated.

Comment: What is the params [@commentable, Comment.new] doing? I'm not quite sure what the `Comment.new` means in this context. Is it just creating a new record similar to when you see it in the controller?

Comment: Because you have a nested route, you need two objects for your `form_for`. The first one is the object to which the comment belongs (`@commentable`) the second one is the new comment object (`Comment.new`). So yes, it's just like creating a new record in the controller. You could do `@comment = Comment.new` in the controller, but you'd have to do that everywhere you have the comment form. It's cleaner to just do `Comment.new` in the view.