# find_commentable returning undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting a `undefined method 'comments' for nil:NilClass` in my create method when I try to create a new comment(polymorphic relationship). I've browsed several other questions regarding this and can't seem to locate what's wrong with my form/controller.

Here is my generic partial for comments:

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Please note that this is rendered in my traveldeal/show page. The form renders fine. If I change the form_for to pass parameters `[@commentable, @comment]`, I get the error `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class`

routes.rb

```
resources :users 
resources :traveldeals

resources :traveldeals do
  resources :comments
end

resources :users do
  resources :comments
end
```

The Railscasts has the above written as `resources :traveldeals, :has_many => :comments`, but I believe this is dated syntax.

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

   if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully saved comment."  
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end

private

  def find_commentable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    nil
   end

end
```

Edit: Added the solution so the code above works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `@commentable` in your `form_for`, but where is that variable set? It seems to be set nowhere and I think that is the cause of the error. Also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116592/84631) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113981/refactoring-form-for-create-method-for-comments-in-a-polymorphic-association).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to your other answer, Mischa. I defined @commentable for page where the form_for is displayed, but now I'm getting directed to the failed path (current_user) when I submit the form so my comment is not being saved.

Comment: What do you mean by "failed path (current_user)"? It may have something to do with the `before_filter` in your comments controller... are you still logged in?

Comment: I meant that my comment is not being saved (the way I have it set up in my controller, I get redirected to current_user if it fails). Yes, I am logged in when I try to create the comment.

Comment: Could you try to find out *why* the comment wasn't saved? Instead of redirecting, try showing the contents of `@comment.errors`.

Comment: Also, could you post what parameters are sent when you submit the comment form? You can find them in `log/development.log`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me again, Mischa! The error was that there was no user ID so I added it in the controller. Solution is posted.